# CDI Injection and @Model Annotation

Tags: ejb, cdi

I have two questions regarding two annotations:

1) Why does the "faceContext" has to be injected from Resources class? Instead, MemberController can directly use "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()" in register() method to obatin a FacesContext object? It seems much simpler to do that.

2) Can @Model be replaced by @Singleton? Or even @ApplicationScoped?

Thanks.

MemberController.java

```
@Model
public class MemberController {

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Inject
private MemberRegistration memberRegistration;

@Produces
@Named
private Member newMember;

@PostConstruct
public void initNewMember() {
    newMember = new Member();
}

public void register() throws Exception {
    try {
        memberRegistration.register(newMember);
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registered!", "Registration successful");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        initNewMember();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, "Registration unsuccessful");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
    }
}
}
```

Resources.java

```
public class Resources {
// use @SuppressWarnings to tell IDE to ignore warnings about field not being referenced directly
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Produces
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Produces
public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}

@Produces
@RequestScoped
public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

injecting the FacesContext istead of getting it using the static factory method has the advantage that you will only once have to care about how to get the current context, when implementing the producer method or field. Each time you need the context you can simply inject it and it is fully transparent to you where it comes from. This might also have some benefits when anything changes in how to get the context, ...

The answer to the second question depends on your requirements. Since @Model is simply a stereotype for @RequestScoped and @Named, you cannot directly replace it with @Singleton or @ApplicationScoped since these both annotations adwise the container to create a single object for all requests. Nevertheless, if this meets your requirements better than having a different object for each request, you are free to change it ;)

Comment: are you saying “@Model” is functionally equal to the combination of "@RequestScoped" + "@Named"? Thanks.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose the Member field is annotated with @Produces? Can't the Member class be directly injected to any class that needs it?

Comment: Yes, "@Model" is a stereotype for "@RequestScoped" and "@Named" and thus functionally equal. The "@Produces" annotation simply 'implements' kind of a factory-method (here it is a field) pattern which produces instances of the EntityManager. You could also directly inject the EntityManager using "@PersistenceContext" anywhere else but using this resource-producer pattern of CDI enables you to use "@Inject" and to inject different instances using qualifiers. This might f.i. be the case if you would need 2 EntityManager instances operating on different databases.